# Loop through Files and replace carriage returns

Tags: powershell, loops, replace, newline, carriage-return

I am trying to loop through some text files and replace the carriage returns this is my code:

```
    $files = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\TESTING\"

 $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $files -rec
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath)  |
    Foreach-object { $_ -replace '\r'+, '' } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

The code works when I replace anything else in the file. But not the carriage returns '\r'.
I have tried entering the carriage return in different ways (\r, `r, [\r] ).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By default, [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) streams the content of a text file *line by line*, with newlines (line endings) invariably getting *stripped* from each line returned.

To preserve the newlines, you must read the file *in full*, as a multi-line string, which is what the `-Raw` switch does:

```
(Get-Content -Raw $file.PSPath) -replace '\r' |
  Set-Content -NoNewLine $file.PSPath
```

**Character encoding caveat**: Note that `Set-Content` uses *its* default encoding, which may differ from that of the input file; use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed.

Note:

- `\r` is a *regex* escape sequence representing a CR (Carriage Return) character, passed via a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), i.e. `'\r'`; since the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) invariably replaces *all* matches of the given regex, matching just a *single* CR (`\r`) is enough.

  - Alternatively, in this simple case, you could have passed a *verbatim* CR character as the regex,
    via an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) containing the [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)  `` `r ``, i.e. `` "`r" ``
- *Not* specifying a replacement expression is effectively the same as passing `''`, i.e results in effective *removal* of the matches from the string.
- [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s `-NoNewLine` switch prevents a trailing newline from getting added to the output file (which, on Windows, would re-introduce a CRF).